# TYPO3 8.5.1 - ATagParams in Menu not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I tried to use `ATagParams` in TypoScript, but the parameter isn't shown in any menu links. A code like this was working in TYPO3 6.2, but not in TYPO3 8.5.1. What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug in TYPO3?

```
lib.mainNav = HMENU
lib.mainNav {
  special = directory
  special.value = 1
  wrap = <nav id="main-nav" class="ui top attached tabular menu">|</nav>
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO {
     allWrap = <div class="item" data-tab="mainitem{elementUid}">|</div>
     subst_elementUid = 1
     ATagParams = class="navlink_inactive"
    }

    ACT = 1
    ACT {
     allWrap = <div class="item active" data-tab="mainitem{elementUid}">|</div>
     subst_elementUid = 1
     ATagParams = class="active"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in 8.6.0.

Maybe you override it in a later TypoScript?
Look into TypoScript Object Browser or/and Template Analyzer.